# Why does C++11 condition variable require a std::mutex?

Tags: c++11, thread-safety, mutex, condition-variable

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) condition variables require a unique_lock on a std::mutex. This seems like an unfortunate design restriction. Why isn't any kind of lock meeting condition [Mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Mutex) acceptable?

Comment: Who would unlock the mutex if you didn't have the unique_lock?

Comment: We have `condition_variable_any` for that.